# adding an openid that is already associated with stackoverflow not working

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, linked-accounts

I have this account, with 2 IDs google and myopenid. I have another at work with a stackexchange ID, and not much experience. I would like to join them, or if not just add the work ID to this account.

So I tried to add the work ID (stackexchange ID). But this logged me out of this account, and into the other.

How can I add the work ID to this account?
How can I now add another stackexchange ID to this account?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way at this point is for us to merge your profiles.

Head on over to https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts and follow the instructions.